# C++ Design pattern for storing objects in std::set

Tags: c++, c++20

I think, many similar topics are on the net, but until now, I haven't found a satisfying answer:
So given the bellow c++ snippet:

```
class Dummy {
public:
    int key;
    int other_member;
    void set_other_member();
};

using DummySet = std::set<Dummy, std::less<>>;
```

So in my app I'm going to store objects in `std::set` but these objects have key member and also have other -- modifiable members and public methods too.

The problem is that `std::set` won't allow non-const operations on its member, so my code will ends-up by decorated with const methods where the name implies, it set something and mutable member declarations, to allow these operations.

**So the question is, is there any design pattern / implementation best practice to clean up my code and get rid of these creepy decorations?**

Comment: Maybe you're easier off with a `std::map` using the key to associated with the corresponding values.

Comment: Your requirement is unclear, please provide a proper example for this.

Comment: Using `mutable` to get around a design flaw is not just "creepy", but downright irresponsible. Don't do it. The point of something being mutable is that it doesn't affect the actual constness. An example is something like a mutex that's required for synchronizing access. The mutex belongs with the object but does not affect its overall state.

Comment: Just wrap the entire class in a `struct` with one `mutable` member.

Comment: It sounds like you decided on `std::set` too soon and should consider a redesign.

Comment: what "creepy decorations" ? Can you please show an example for the code you want to get rid of?

Comment: use `mutable` or `set<Dummy*>` or `erase` and re`insert` . I don't know any other solution without redesign.

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::unordered_map<key_type,Dummy>` or simple map if you need greater/lesser as @πάντα ῥεῖ pointed.

```
class Dummy {
    int key; //make sure key is unique per instance
public:
    Dummy(int _key, int _other_member) :key(_key), other_member(_other_member) {}
    int get_key() const { return key; }
    int other_member;
    void set_other_member(int _other_member) { other_member = _other_member; };
};

using DummyMap = std::map<int,Dummy,std::less<>>;

int main()
{
    Dummy a(1, 1);
    Dummy b(2, 2);
    DummyMap my_map=DummyMap();
    my_map.emplace(a.get_key(), a);
    my_map.emplace(b.get_key(), b);
    auto it = my_map.find(a.get_key());
    if (it!=my_map.end()) {
        std::cout<<it->second.other_member;
        it->second.set_other_member(5);
    }
}
```

Any change in `Dummy` members could change its position in heap (`std::set`) since `compare` function takes as argument whole `Dummy`. If you use `mutable` along with `const` you simply hide problem but not resolve it. If it will compile any change on `mutable` member of `Dummy` will be ignored and this `Dummy` might be at wrong position in heap. If you insist to use `set` with `mutable` members force `operator <` of Dummy to work with `non mutable` `key` member:

```
class Dummy {
    int key;
public:
    Dummy(int _key, int _other_member) :key(_key), other_member(_other_member) {}
    int get_key() const { return key; }
    mutable int other_member;
    void set_other_member(int _other_member) const { other_member = _other_member; };
    bool operator<(const Dummy& to_compare) const
    {
        return this->key < to_compare.key;
    }
};

using DummySet = std::set<Dummy,std::less<>>;
```